# Azure Active Directory SSO (SAML protocol) when frontend is decoupled from backend. How will frontend be notified that validation is completed?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, nestjs, single-sign-on, decoupling

So I would like to add [SSO using Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol).
My stack consists of a React app as frontend and a NestJS API as backend(decoupled). The scenario looks like the following

1. User clicks login button
2. I create a new window (popup) which leads the user to the Azure AD login page (step 3 in the diagram)
3. After the user logs in to Azure AD successfully Azure AD will POST the SAML response to a redirect URL I have provided them (let's say http://myapp.com/saml) (step 5 in the diagram) (This redirect URL, to my understanding, has to be an endpoint in the NestJS api since React frontend can't handle post request.)
4. NestJS will handle the post request get the info it needs, validates etc etc and then `NestJS has to return a Token to the frontend somehow` in order for the frontend to store that token in a cookie and be able use it in subsequent requests to the NestJS api so that NestJS will be able to know that this user is logged in. (Step 6)

My issue with this approach is that I don't know how will the client get the token when the the validation is completed from NestJS. If this was a coupled application this would not be an issue since the backend would handle the post request set a cookie and redirect the user. But in this case NestJS can't redirect the user since react handles the routing.
What is the correct approach to handle this?
I thought maybe this could work by using websockets...so that when NestJS handles the post request it can send a message to the user which message will contain the token and then the frontend can add it to a cookie and redirect the user to a protected page.

[image]

Comment: Have you got an update on this, and have you implemented it? Can you explain how

Answer (score 1):

(1) Does the frontend really need to store a token to send to the backend on subsequent requests? What if the backend set a cookie at Step 7 in your diagram? Then the cookie would be sent to the backend on subsequent requests. The cookie would be scoped to the backend’s domain name and path. Keeping tokens away from the frontend has the advantage that you can keep them safe from being accessed via a Cross-Site Scripting attack on your frontend, if your backend’s cookie has the HttpOnly attribute set.

(2) If you still need to communicate info from the backend to the frontend in Step 7, then send an HTTP 301 response with the Location header set to your frontend’s URL with the info you want to communicate included in the query or hash portion of the URL. For example, after validating in Step 6, in Step 7 your backend’s HTTP 301 response could have the Location header set to https://my-frontend-domain.com?user=bob or set to https://my-frontend-domain.com#user=bob. With ?user=bob, user=bob would get sent over the network again when the browser requests https://my-frontend-domain.com/?user=bob, whereas with #user=bob it would not. Then the frontend’s JavaScript can read user=bob from the URL.